# PyQt thread execution timeout in the background for macOS

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

When I click the minimize button to perform this operation in the background，Threads often execute beyond the limited time，
Waking up the program in the background is back to normal.
Please be patient, it will appear in about a minute.
[image]

[image]

```
import sys, random, time, functools
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QHBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, QObject

def clock(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def clocked(*args, **kwargs):
        t0 = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        elapsed = time.time() - t0
        name = func.__name__
        l_arg = []
        if args:
            l_arg.append(', '.join(repr(arg) for arg in args))
        arg_str = ', '.join(l_arg)
        print('[%0.5fs] %s(%s)' % (elapsed, name, arg_str))
        return result
    return clocked

@clock
def go_sleep(sleep_time):
    time.sleep(sleep_time)

def go_run():
    for i in range(100):
        go_sleep(random.randint(1, 3))

class WorkThread(QObject):
    def __int__(self):
        super(WorkThread, self).__init__()

    def run(self):
        go_run()

class WinForm(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(WinForm, self).__init__(parent)
        self.button1 = QPushButton('Run')
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClick)
        self._thread = QThread(self)
        self.wt = WorkThread()
        self.wt.moveToThread(self._thread)
        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        main_frame = QWidget()
        main_frame.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_frame)

    def onButtonClick(self):
        self.button1.setText('Running')
        self._thread.started.connect(self.wt.run)
        self._thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = WinForm()
    form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @eyllanesc Hi, Have you encountered this problem？

Comment: I am using macOS, this is related to the operating system, it can work normally in Windows.

Comment: I tried to use setPriority on my QThread and use caffeinate to execute script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turn App Nap back off

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAppSleepDisabled -bool YES
```